# uncaught typeerror $(...).swipe is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

Iam trying to make a swipeable menu in blogger and this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B2Iusn9ixPQ2cFFldHoweXRsWms"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" &amp;&amp; direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" &amp;&amp; direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });

    </script>
```

and Iam getting this error at " $(".swipe-area").swipe({" : uncaught typeerror $(...).swipe is not a function

PLease Help,
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a minimal HTML-example as well? ... Besides, I see some oddness with your ampersands (&&): `if (phase=="move" &amp;&amp; ...`

Comment: when i try to make it "&&" i and save template it gives me an error 'The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.'

Comment: where is swipe function being defined ....in the googledrive script? `swipe()` is not a jQuery core method

Comment: googledrive script is jquery.touchSwipe.min.js

Comment: Iam following this tutorial : http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-swipeable-side-menu-for-the-web/ and getting the page source by chrome at :http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/touch-swipe/demo3.php

Comment: sorry if i was hard to understand I am just a beginner i want to make a blog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
  $("p").on("swipe",function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });                       
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>If you swipe me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Swipe me away!</p>
    <p>Swipe me too!</p>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

**Update** - Unexpected token

There is a **syntax error** in your code in below line

```
swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
```

Correct syntax - In below way, you can define *swipeStatus* a function

```
var swipeStatus  = function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
```

Comment: Its working for me. Not sure why still you are getting that error.

Comment: ok this is my code now http://pastebin.com/91jHT7uJ but there is an error in " swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) " 'Unexpected token )'

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
  $("p").on("swipe",function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });                       
});
</script>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Always post code with explanations relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Ans:

load all jquery dependencies first , then load touchSwipe library